# Angular inserted HTML not attached to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use Angular to create a popover that contains a `<textarea>` and a `<button>` to perform an action.

I followed [this guide](http://subliminalsources.com/9/building-angularjs-bootstrap-components-popover-directive-part-1/) to create my popover with a custom directive.

My problem is that the content in the popover doesn't appear to be attached to the main controller anymore when it is inserted.  The contents of the `<textarea>` does not display with `{{ textarea }}`, and the `ng-click="click()"` does not trigger the `$scope.click` function defined in the controller.

Maybe this is due to the fact that the content of the popover is being set in the directive, instead of being declared in the `view1.html` document?  Any help would be appreciated.

I've made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzj26mzm/7/) which demonstrates the issue - it is very slightly simplified from the code below, but the problem is demonstrated just fine.

## directives.js:

```
module.directive('customPopover', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            $(el).popover({
                trigger: attrs.popoverTrigger,
                html: true,
                content: function() {return $('#popover_content').html();},
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

## pages/view1.html:

```
<div>
    <div id="controls">
        <a custom-popover class="btn" 
            tabindex="0"
            popover-html="copyPaste" 
            popover-placement="right"
            popover-trigger="click" 
            role="button">Copy & paste data</a>

    </div>

    <div id="popover_content" style="display:none;">
        <textarea id="textBox" type="text" ng-model="textarea"></textarea>
        <button id="submitDataBtn" ng-click="click()" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>

    {{ textarea }}
</div>
```

## controller.js

```
var module = angular.module("moduleName", ['ngRoute']);

module.controller("SimpleController", function ($scope, gsatfFactory, $sce, $location) {
    $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.table = $sce.trustAsHtml(gsatfFactory.parseData($scope.textarea));
        $location.path('view2');
    };
});

module.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/view1.html',
            controller: 'SimpleController'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/view2.html',
            controller: 'SimpleController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="moduleName">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
        <script src="js/factory.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content html isn't angular compiled. Use this to compile it:

```
$compile($('#popover_content').html())(scope);
```

your directive:

```
mod.directive('customPopover', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            $(el).popover({
                trigger: attrs.popoverTrigger,
                html: true,
                content: function() {return $compile($('#popover_content').html())(scope);},
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Correct. Here is a plnkr to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/m3EsBMS8Nq2YlYwhrS5X?p=preview